# clang++ C++11 invocation

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Although there are some questions here concerning the C++11 support of clang, I don't seem to be able to get `clang++` to eat my C++11 code.

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 2.9 (tags/RELEASE_29/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

According to [the clang C++11 status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) I should have at least partial support (e.g. right angle brackets), but it refuses all features I tested.

**Is there any switch to tell clang to use C++11?**

---

Example test:

```
$ clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ cpp11.cpp 
cpp11.cpp:16:33: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
  std::vector<std::pair<int,char>> xs;
                                ^~
                                > >
cpp11.cpp:18:8: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  auto y = x;
  ~~~~ ^
2 errors generated
```

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, but it chokes horribly on that argument (about two pages of error messages and a final Segfault).

Comment: Is this the Apple version or the base version?  Asking because I reported an Apple bug to the main site and got flamed :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: No, it's not Apple. Plain Linux/GNU.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ildjarn points out the correct argument, `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`. The errors you're getting with that argument may be because the version of libstdc++ you're using uses some C++11, or non-standard C++, that clang 2.9 doesn't support.

Comment: Try something along the lines of `clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ ...` (assuming, of course, you have libc++ installed).

Comment: @Huw: Yes, I just realised I have the option between `libc++` and `libstdc++` and so far I was too lazy to compile `clang` or `llvm` myself, so I got it from my package sources, which do not include `libc++` and if I believe the project documentation that library is only available for Mac. Which means it's not available for me, right?

Comment: @bitmask: Yeah, it doesn't look like it's available for non-OS X system, alas.

Comment: @bitmask I just did a quick google search and came up with an article that might help: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/llvm-clang-libc-linux/

Comment: @Huw: I think libc++ was ported successfully to a few Linux distributions. Windows port is ongoing. The problem is that the further away from OSX architecture you get, the more you have to provide for the port. That and the Windows port faces MSVC++ craziness.