# Why does vscode give me an error when trying to implement vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, g++

I've been trying to learn to use vector of vectors to create matrices in c++. I have checked my compiler, it is Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3). The error I am getting is:

`vect = {1,2,3,4};`

*main.cpp:12:10: error: expected expression*

`vector<vector<double>> mat;`

*main.cpp:26:23: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')*

Can someone help me? please! I don't know what needs to be done.

Comment: Check which C++ standard you are using.  C++98 requires a space between the `> >` otherwise it is considered one token rather than two closing tokens.  (That has since been changed (corrected, imo) in the C++11 standard.

Comment: See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303955/clang-c11-invocation) that shows up if you google the text of your error message

Answer (score 0):

You have to add white space between `> >`

```cpp
 vector<vector<double> > mat;
```

(In pre-C++11 compilers you need to leave a space, `> >`)

Comment: Thank you!! still having issue with the main.cpp:12:10: error: expected expression tho. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I don't have source code of your `main.cpp` file, so can't say anything. It would be better to ask a new question for that. As this question was for some other issue.